# How to chang http local in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

Dear help if you know about change local http://127.0.0.1:8000 to name `http:test.con`

Comment: is it just to run php arisan serve ?

Answer (score 0):

you can run the following command:

```
php artisan serve --host=some-domain.test --port=anyPort
```

Comment: Erro: 

Starting Laravel development server: http://some-domain.test:3306
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Sun Aug 21 00:08:29 2022] PHP Warning:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Aug 21 00:08:29 2022] Failed to listen on some-domain.test:3306 (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Comment: This one command , me run : php artisan serve --host=some-domain.test --port=3306